S3 video unable to play in browser
I have uploaded a video in my S3 bucket, but when I try to play it directly by clicking on the Object URL inside the "Object overview section", all I see is a video player with a black screen.
When I download the same video from the S3 it plays fine on my PC.
The video is .mp4 (MPEG-4) format.
I have tried changing the bucket policy to:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::name-of-my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::name-of-my-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I also turned off Block public access (bucket settings)
Object Ownership is set to "Bucket owner enforced", ACLs disabled.
The value inside the metadata is "video/mp4".
Object Lock is disabled.
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

What do you see in your browser's devtools' Network activity tab?

What codec is the video and audio?  Does the file play in a browser if you open the local copy into the browser?

@AnonCoward with MediaInfo software I'm seeing Codec Id: isom (isom/iso2/mp41). I just tried to open the local copy with Chrome and it gives me the same result, just a video player with a black screen. So it could be a codec issue?

@Dai I'm seeing 206 Status code for the media and several 200 status codes. Not sure if I should look into anything specific?

Yes.  You've identified its h.264, but that contains many profiles and options, only some of which Chrome supports.  If the file won't play in Chrome, no doubt the file is out of spec for it.

@AnonCoward A few years ago I ran into the same problem, except the problem wasn't a lack of codecs on the client-side, but that the Content-Type was insufficiently specific - I ended-up having to scan all of my video files with ffprobe and mp4box to re-generate the full and exact Content-Type  codecs= parameter and then it worked reliably in all browsers/devices - I'd have thought they'd be happy with just container-level info video/mp4...
